# Elements aligned to right inside 1200px

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Currently i have the following page on this website which on my screen looks really good screenshot #1 But then the issue comes when resizing the screen and test the responsiveness for larger monitors screenshot #2

How can i keep this section on differents screen sizes? So that the text does not move far?

thank you guys!

[image: normal screen]
[image: resized screen]

Comment: Please add some code and do also what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

On your main content container style, add `max-width: 1200px;`. If you haven't already, to center it add `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: How are you so positive that will solve his problem given he has not supplied any markup you can test with? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

use css media query for instance

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:960px){
        /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
        body{
          background: red;
        }
    }
```

or if you like, you can use

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/* styles for browsers smaller than 960px; */
 /* write your css here*/
}`enter code here`
```